# Redirect rule in .htaccess to catch all URL's that are not in the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have used Stackoverflow a lot to find answers to my questions, but this time I can not find an answer. Maybe it is because english is not my native language and therefore I can not find the right query to search.

I have created a .htaccess files for redirects from our current website to our new website on a new domain. The .htaccess file has 266 rules now and it works fine (I have tested several rules and the redirects work fine on a individual level).

Now my question: I would like to create an extra rule that catches all the remaining URL's that are not in the .htaccess file and redirect all of that URL's to the new homepage. These include pages that we will not create on the new domain because they are outdated or pages that we maybe forgot etc.

I have tried several rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

But this redirects all URL's to the new homepage, so it ignores all other rules I have made in de .htaccess file. Even if I put the rule in the end of the file.

I hope you guys can help! tnx in advance!

Pike

Answer (score 0):

this may be not help much, but the "L" Flag tells Apache not to process any more rules if this one is used.
try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,NC]
```

and more rewrite cheatsheets in [here](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)

Comment: Thanks for your help suwidadi, but unfortunately this did not do the trick. Results are the same: Every URL gets redirected to home. If someone else has a solution it is much appreciated!